# ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework bundling startup times

Tags: asp.net, caching, bundle, bundling-and-minification, web-optimization

I've been using some of the bundling and minification functionality in the Web Optimization Framework and really like everything about it so far aside from what seems to be some fairly aggressive cache clearing and a not insignificant first-run cost.

The first run, that presumably bundles and minifies the resources, takes approximately 3-5 seconds to run on a cold start. Not too bad, but it seems to drop the resources out of the cache fairly aggressively on my live server. I have fairly low traffic sites that suffer from these cold start times commonly, so wondered if there is any way to programmatically modify the bundling framework to less aggressively clear caches or to generate the minified files during the publish process? Perhaps I'm using the wrong framework to achieve this?

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated!